# Can I use package 'imputation' in R version 3.0.3?

Tags: r, package

I am using R version 3.0.3.

I would like to install the package "imputation". I would like to re-run an analysis I used last year in R version 3.0.2.

I also have a new computer so I am re-installing my packages. I would like to install the package "imputation".

```
install.packages("imputation")
```

However, I received the following error:

```
Installing package into ‘\\oxdc/userdata/jolyon.faria/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘imputation’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3)
```

How can I work around this problem? I thought I could perhaps run two versions of R on the same computer but this may throw up its own problems.

Answer (score 1):

Always check CRAN for package problems:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputation/

You might be able to get it working on 3.0.3 or later by installing from source via the source archive.

Or contact the maintainer and ask them if they can fix the problem that caused the removal from CRAN.